# Using getCriteria with a custom element type

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, elementtype, custom, element

I've setup a custom element type for badges for a system I'm building, but I've run into some trouble trying to query for badges using `craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Badges_Badge);`, however I'm getting an error saying 'Undefined class constant 'Badges_Badge', but when I loop through all element types using getAllElementTypes() I see an entry for 'Badges_Badges', and I'm able to add and edit badges in the cms.

Is it impossible to query for custom elements using getCriteria, or am I missing something more fundamental?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it for now by including a custom enum class in the base plugin file:

```
abstract class CustomElementType extends BaseEnum
{
    const Badges_Badge = 'Badges_Badge';
}
```

and then querying for the custom element in the plugin using `craft()->elements->getCriteria(CustomElementType::Badges_Badge);`

Answer (score 0):

`ElementType` is a native Craft class, so it doesn't know about the `Badges_Badge` const you're trying to access.

You can either do it by adding your own class that adds a `Badges_Badge` const, [like you discovered](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/19830/57), or simply use:

```
craft()->elements->getCriteria('Badges_Badge');
```